# How to run console application on azure?

Tags: azure, console

I have trial account on azure cloud. I created a virtual server. I created console application with superwebsocket. I uploaded the application on azure virtual servers desktop. I created tcp endpoind (2012 port) on azure virtual desktop configuration. But my test code didnt connect the app with websocket via ws://myuseradress.cloudapp.net:2012.

ps: my console app works in my desktop and I connect with test code via ws://localhost:2012

Comment: did you open up the port on the cloud VM's firewall for port 2012?

Comment: I create endpoint port public and private (2012) from virtual machine endpoint tab.

Comment: Creating an endpoint configures the Azure LB. But in IaaS, doesn't update the VM's firewall (PaaS does). So you'll need to manually ensure the VM's firewall is allowing inbound connections on port 2012.

Comment: @brent - perhaps enter your suggestion as an Answer, so onder can properly mark it as such...

Comment: you can run it on Azure Pipelines, checkout. https://devsdaily.com/azure-devops-how-to-run-console-applications-on-azure-pipeline/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an endpoint in Windows Azure IaaS Cloud Services, this configures the Azure Fabric's load balancer to route requests on that port to the specific VM's that are associated with that endpoint. However, since this is IaaS and PaaS, Windows Azure does not automatically configure the VM itself to accept that connection. So you much log into the VM and ensure that its internal firewall is allowing inbound connections on the appropriate port.